# Libnoise bounding box - from spherical to planar

Tags: c++, javascript, python, maps, projection

I'm trying to convert a bounding box inside a spherical map (equirectangular image as a result of Libnoise/c++) into a planar projection, but I can't find the correct algorithm for it and I'm not good at projections.

I'm using Javascript and Python and I've been trying to adapt some libraries I've found that convert equirectangular images into cubemaps, but those work by processing each face separately and I find it extremely complicated to adapt such libraries to process just a bounding box of the equirectangular result.

[This is the library](https://github.com/thomcc/equirect-to-cubemap-faces/blob/master/index.js) I'm using as a reference.

[And this is the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUxBu.jpg) of what I'm trying to do with the resulting image.

I know I'll have some distortions and that the resulting image will be "narrower" when heading closer to the poles, so I'm planing to calculate such offsets regarding to the bounding box to cover the desired area.

This would allow me to work on the map using XY flat coordinates, without the spherical distortion.

Comment: "This would allow me to work on the map using XY flat coordinates, without the spherical distortion."

No. It would somewhat reduce the maximum distortion, but there is no distortion-free mapping from the surface of a sphere to a plane. Your best bet to reduce distortion is to eliminate the equirectangular step altogether. Generate your noise in the planar domain you're using for display, so you don't have to hack around equirectangular coordinates with their nasty pole at all.

Comment: Hi DMGregory, thanks for your reply. 

By doing that, how would I keep the seamless factor that the spherical mapping provides me? I need to be able to use the texture for a spherical mapping, that once you zoom in it renders a planar representation of that same generated noise. Is this possible? I don't mind dealing with a little bit of distortion if it isn't too extreme. Thanks once again!

Comment: You'd still compute your noise in the 3D spherical domain, but just skip over projecting it to an equirectangular intermediate that you don't actually want to display.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost on how to do that... I can see that Libnoise just gives me the option to put the noise model inside a sphere, a plane or a cylinder. Once I put the model inside a sphere it exports an equirectangular image.

This is the guide I'm following http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial8.html